# Reactstrap Modal doesn't fade in but fades out

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I'm building a header that has a login link with Reactstrap. When the user clicks the login link, a modal should appear showing the different options for logging in. Here's my code:

```
export default class Header extends Component {
    state = {
        isOpen: false,
        modal: false
    }
    toggle = () => this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen })
    toggleModal = () => this.setState({ modal: !this.state.modal })
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar light expand="md">
                    <NavbarBrand href="/">VoteMole</NavbarBrand>
                    <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
                    <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
                        <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
                            <NavLink href="#" onClick={this.toggleModal}>
                                <NavItem>Login</NavItem>
                            </NavLink>
                        </Nav>
                    </Collapse>
                </Navbar>
                <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggleModal}>
                    <ModalBody>Lorem Ipsum</ModalBody>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the modal only fades out but doesn't fade in. By default the Modal component has the fade prop set to true. I've tried manually setting it with `fade={true}` or with just the shorthand `fade`. It didn't solve the issue. I've tried setting the modalTransition and backdropTransition props to trigger the fade effect. It still didn't work. Can someone please help with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this seems to be a bug with reactstrap. See the open Github issue here: https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/607

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wondering is the bug occurring only on React 16? Because the example in the documentation works fine and I'm assuming that's using an older version of React.